# How to solve a Secret file bindings issue

Tags: android, jenkins, binding, gradle, continuous-integration

I have a problem with one of my jenkins build.

I have configured in my global credentials, a **keystore** for one of my android build. This keystore is needed for when I have to sign my apk in order to distribute my app on Google Play for example.

So in the job, I have configured a **Secret file binding** to allow jenkins to copy the keystore file to a temporary location and sets a variable, let's call it SECRET_PATH, to that location. I can then provide gradle with the value of this variable on the command line when **invoking the gradle script** (in the switches section).

But then the build fails each time :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':myapp:packageRelease'.
> Failed to read key ******** from store "/home/jenkins/slave/secretFiles/3607aab3-6e27-497a-b198-7d9a3aeb2913/keystore": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

it is as if the location **/home/jenkins/slave/secretFiles/3607aab3-6e27-497a-b198-7d9a3aeb2913/keystore** didn't even exist.

In the job configuration, the help tip on the **Bindings** sections also mentions this :

```
Warning: if the master or slave node has multiple executors, any other build running concurrently on the same node will be able to read the contents of this file.
```

It is exactly as if another concurrent build were running and deleted the location where the keystore was. This is really weird.

One more thing, I am using a master/slave topology where everything is dockerized. Not sure the docker itself is involved though. I think it's purely a Jenkins issue but I am giving this information so that you guys have some context.

Have you guys ever experienced this weird behaviour where jenkins seems to be unable to "resolve" the secret file bindings ?
Any help would be really appreciated.

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

> `Failed to read key ******** from store "/home/jenkins/slave/secretFiles/3607aab3-6e27-497a-b198-7d9a3aeb2913/keystore": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect`
>
> it is as if the location `/.../keystore` didn't even exist.

No, the error message is correct — the  file *does* exist, but most likely the store password or key password you are providing is incorrect.

If the keystore *did not* exist, you would get an error something like:
`File '/.../release.keystore' specified for property 'signingConfig.storeFile' does not exist.`

You can double check this by running `file $SECRET_PATH/keystore`, or `ls -l  $SECRET_PATH/keystore`, or using `keytool` or something similar.

---

You don't mention injecting the keystore and key password(s) at all into the job — how are you doing that?

First make sure that building and signing the release version works as expected with Gradle from the command line.

Then you could try doing the same in Jenkins, by passing in the filename and password via the Gradle step (though this isn't a great idea if you're using the Job Config History plugin, for example).

Once that works, you can use the credential binding plugin to inject the file, and to inject the password.